# What is the meaning of "Atomicity" in DBMS?

Tags: sql, rdbms

In my Database course means "Failures".

Is it right meaning or not because, I'm confused from it.

Please give me example of it to be clear

Comment: Can you please describe in more details what exactly you are looking for!?

Comment: Please refer [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems))

Comment: There are 2 uses for the word 'atomicity' in DB context--transactions & 1NF. Which do you mean? How are you stuck answering this?

Answer (score 3):

Atomicity is standing for 'A' in ACID Properties in DBMS. Atomicity simply means if the transaction you are going to commit, is fully complete to a database is correct,we can commit the transaction. Say in a school database we have fully entered details of a new student who is going to register.
If the transaction is incomplete or wrong, we don't commit the transaction to the database.If student has not given all the details required, we wait to collect all the student details, then submit to the student database.
 This means all or nothing. This feature helps when we or another user uses database, all the data is complete, no incomplete transaction is done.

Comment: :thumbsup: for this simple explanation. Could it be characterized as analogous to an XML's "well-formedness"? Like if a tag is not closed correctly etc., it's incomplete or unbalanced, therefore, invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Atomicity is also known as the all-or-nothing rule. And also it can be defined as the entire transaction that should be done at a time or doesn't take place.
Consider an example that there are two transactions A and B. A has 200$ and B has 500$, suppose A wants to transfer 100$ to account B. A's transaction is completed but B doesn't receive the amount then here the problem will occur.
This results in an inconsistent database state. Therefore, the transaction must be executed in its entirety in order to ensure the correctness of the database state.

Comment: This adds nothing to the many old answers already here. [answer] [Help] PS [tour]